# WebSphere Liberty + Springboot + Hibernate + JNDI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jndi, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am trying to migrate my small application from Tomcat to WebSphere. In order to do so, I am rebuilding it from scratch addressing major components separately. I am struggling with data access / JNDI on webSphere Liberty. I get

javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:comp/env/jdbc/test

SERVER.xml

```
<featureManager>
<feature>webProfile-8.0</feature>
<feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
<feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
<feature>javaee-8.0</feature>
<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
<feature>concurrent-1.0</feature>
```

```
 <dataSource id="test" jndiName="jdbc/test" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib" />
    <properties databaseName="test" serverName="localhost" portNumber="3306" user="user" password="mypassword" />
    <jdbcDriver>
      <library id="MySQLLib">
        <fileset dir="/Library/JDBC/" includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar" />
      </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
  </dataSource>
```

Data config class

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/jdbc/test", name="java:comp/env/jdbc/test")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

I have also tried this approach :

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `DataSourceConfig` class. Just specify `spring.datasource,jndi-name` in your configuration and Spring Boot will do the lookup.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing I notice is that you have 2 `<jdbcDriver>` elements in your server.xml -- only one should be used, like this:

```xml
 <dataSource id="test" jndiName="jdbc/test" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <properties databaseName="test" serverName="localhost" portNumber="3306" user="user" password="mypassword" />
    <jdbcDriver>
      <library id="MySQLLib">
        <fileset dir="/Library/JDBC/" includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar" />
      </library>
    </jdbcDriver>
  </dataSource>
```

Next, you are defining a resource reference like this:

```java
@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/jdbc/test", name="java:comp/env/jdbc/test")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

This effectively says "peform a JNDI lookup of 'java:comp/env/jdbc/test' and bind it to the 'java:comp/env/jdbc/test' JNDI name". This would result in an infinite loop or circular reference.

Instead, you want to bind the `lookup` to the `jndiName` that you have defined in your server.xml like this:

```java
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/test", name="java:comp/env/jdbc/test")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Or, if that doesn't work you can try a direct lookup the Spring way like this:

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws NamingException {
    return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test");
}
```

or with Java standard API:

```java
DataSource ds = javax.naming.InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/test");
```

If none of these options work, check your server logs for errors or warnings. There ought to be some indication of why the DataSource cannot be created.

---

### New in Liberty 19.0.0.9 -- datasource validation API

In 19.0.0.9 we released a REST API that can be used to validate configuration elements such as `dataSource`s.

To use it with your config, configure an admin user (if you haven't already) like this:

```xml
<quickStartSecurity userName="adminuser" userPassword="adminpwd"/>
```

And then in a web browser go to `https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/validation/dataSource/{DATASOURCE_ID}` which would be https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/validation/dataSource/test in your case.

To get a full walkthrough of this validation feature, see [this post](https://openliberty.io/blog/2019/09/13/testing-database-connections-REST-APIs.html).

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. I have moved to 10.0.0.9 and used the utility to confirm my JNDI worked. I still have an issue with data (CrudRepository/JPA with Spring probably) but your answer helped me move forward and confirm that part. I think I will open another question to keep things clear on StackOverflow and avoid confusion for others

Answer (score 2):

This mostly looks correct, except have the lookup match the jndiName that is configured in server.xml,

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/test", name="java:comp/env/jdbc/test")
private DataSource dataSource;
```